# Chrome to show the collocation different

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

sorry about my English... , I am very new with html/css .. , My probleme:
I have to write this [Codec](https://codepen.io/mezb/pen/qKjroP) .
CSS Codec:

```
body {
 background-color: #ebf5d7;
 grid-gap: 5px;
 grid-template-columns: 10% 72% 17%;
 grid-template-areas:

 "header   header   header"   
 "nav      nav      nav" 
 "linkBox  linkBox  linkBox"    
 "main     main     main"     
 "infoBox  infoBox  infoBox"  
 "footer   footer   footer" ;  
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
body {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 10% 72% 17%;
 grid-template-areas:
"header  header  header" 
"nav     nav     nav"     
"linkBox main    infoBox"
"footer  footer  footer";
 }
}
body > header {
grid-area: header;
background-image: url("../my2.png");
padding: 60px;
}

body > nav {
grid-area: nav;
background-color: #d2f5c4;

}

body > #externalLinks {
grid-area: linkBox;
background-color:  #d2f3c6;

}   
body > main {
grid-area: main;
background-color: #eaf6e5;
}

body > #furtherInformation {
grid-area: infoBox;
background-color: #d2f3c6;
}

body > footer {
grid-area: footer;
background-color: #99ee7a;

}
```

/* Nav  */

```
nav {background-color: #d2f5c4;font-size: 17px;}    
nav a{  
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
display: inline;
padding: 0px 8px;
font-size: 17px;
font-family:  Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, sans-serif;
}

nav ul {list-style-type: none;}   

nav li {display: block;display:inline-block}
```

/* ExternalLinks  */

```
#externalLinks a    {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px ;
font-size: 17px;
font-family:  Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, sans-serif;  
}

#externalLinks ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 5px;
padding: 0;
}

#externalLinks li{float: left}
```

/* to give the Link1, link2, link3 ; Colors , Padding, .... */

```
li a, .dropbtn {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;

}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn { background-color: #f1ebeb;}

.dropdown-content {
display: none; 
position: absolute; 
background-color: #f1f1f1 ;
min-width: 160px; 
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
z-index: 1;                                 
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;               
display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #9f9e9e;
}
```

/* Open the inside Links */

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: inline-block;
left: 103px;
top: 214px;
}
```

/* Footer  */

```
#copry {
overflow: auto;
font-size: 2px;
list-style-type: none;
font-family:  Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, sans-serif;
}   

#img1 {float: left;margin-bottom: 3px;}
#copry a {text-decoration: none;margin-bottom: 3px;}
#copry p {font-size: 10px;margin-bottom: 0;}
```

When it to see to my Firefox it see this ,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbzWU.png) , but when I see it with Chrome Browser this see this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLvyN.png) , i am very new with html/css .. , i don't know why this window on Chrome.. , can please anyone help me to remedy this problem , Thanks !

Comment: So your question boils down to "Why doesn't my header image show in Chrome?" Try creating a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting all this code, or put it in a JSFiddle.

Comment: hallo , my problem was not the "heard show" , rather that links from left column , different order had , one with Firefox and another with Chrome...

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer you figured out. 

I don't see the word "News" anywhere in the code you posted... next time post the relevant code and your real question ("why is 'Books' to the right of 'News' instead of beneath it?")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to found the problem... , in my CSS codec , in #externalLinks a .

```
#externalLinks a    {

text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px ;
font-size: 17px;
font-family:  Candara, Calibri, Segoe, Optima, sans-serif;
```

}

The problem was , **padding: 5px ;** , now **without** it , is all gut !!